# What database can I use for android programming?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am new to android programming and database. I have very little experience with database. I am trying to make users login from different phones. I think I read that SQLite will not be suitable for this. Basically, I want the user's data to synch with different phones.

I want to know what type of database I could use. Thanks!

Comment: sqlite is a local database on every device. you need something centralized, e.g. a server-based database. but regardless, the question's offtopic. We're here to answer programming questions, not recommend for/against any particular product.

Comment: Dear friend, you should learn to use Google...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use a database in the cloud, a server, not in Android.